# pushing nodejs app on heroku master

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, port, heroku-cli

I've created a server for my front end project using nodejs on the back end.
after testing it successfully on my computer(localhost:3001),I wanted to deploy it on heroku.

to do so, I ran the following codes on gitbash(windows) :

```
1-git init
2-git add .
3-git commit -m "my 1st commit"
4-heroku create 
5-git remote -v
6-heroku rgit:remote -a blah-blah-21222
7-git push heroku master
```

here's the error I stumbled upon :

```
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/blah-blah-21222.git'
```

I even changed the last line of my codes on server.js Which initially was :

```
app.listen(3001,()=>{
    console.log('app is running on port 3001');
})
```

and switched it to :

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT||3001,()=>{
    console.log(`app is running on port ${process.env.PORT}`);
})
```

I got the same error as well and I don't feel like if this port change is the main challenge in the first place.

Do you have any idea how I can deploy this nodejs server on heroku ?

Answer (score 1):

You should [create a named app](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/creating-apps) with command :

```
heroku create blah-blah-21222  // blah-blah-21222 is name you want (not duplicate)
```

When you use:

```
heroku create
```

`heroku` create random name for you, please sure thas name is `blah-blah-21222`
Try it and see any error ?

Comment: yeah,the same. I got these for a made-up name :

remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to jooje.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/jooje.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/jooje.git'

Comment: Are you login heroku ?

And when create, it log that you create success ?

Comment: I know this way is idiod, but you can try delete it and create again.

Comment: this is what I get :

 parse error: Expected another key-value pair at line 10, column 3
remote:  !     Unable to parse package.json
remote: -----> Build failed
remote: parse error: Expected another key-value pair at line 10, column 3
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: !       Push rejected to jooje.
To https://git.heroku.com/jooje.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/jooje.git'

Comment: CAn you upload package.json , I see `Unable to parse package.json`